# Renaming an variable type

Tags: c++, variables, renaming

I'm not entirely sure what this is called, but I think it is very easy to do.

I have seen some people rename the types of variables to make their code easier to read.
Let's say I have a shop of items and they need a int "itemId".

How could I define so that I can say:

```
Item getItem(ID itemId);
```

Insteath of:

```
Item getItem(int itemId);
```

I don't nessesarily know if it's any useful to always change code like that. But I would at the very least want the knowledge to know how to do it. Anyways, I'm quite sure it's almost as easy as:

```
#define ID as int;
```

or something in that manner. But I just were not able to look it up as I don't remember what the action is called x)
Thanks

Comment: You are looking for typedef

Comment: @hamon Actualy, OP's looking for a [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11:

```
using ID = int;
```

C++11 and previous standards:

```
typedef int ID;
```

Comment: I do have c++11, can also get the 12th edition from my school. But I assume the c++11 version is preferred over the older ones then, since they changed it?

Comment: @AleksanderFimreite whether it is preferred in this case is still a matter of opinion. But `using` lets you do come [interesting stuff with templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), and that, together with this simple non-template case are somehow unified by syntax. So I expect more people will use the C++11 version as they get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

both `#define ID int` and `typedef int ID` can work and will have the same effect in your example; But there are differences between the two: the first defines a string literal which will be replaced with "int" at compile time, while the second defines a new data type. 
The later is the recommended way, as it is less error prone.